# How to build lookup table for JEPG Huffman Values

Tags: jpeg, huffman-code

I think I read [itu-t81.pdf](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf) document a few times. But I couldn't figure out how to get block data (DC and AC values) from bit stream.

The problem is that I couldn't understand how to get huffman values from bit stream. In **Annex F** section **F.2.2.3 The DECODE procedure** describes DECODE, EXTEND and decoder tables.

Question 1: I think I must build decoder tables after (or while) parsed DHT marker, am I right?

Question 2: The figure **Figure F.15 – Decoder table generation** uses **HUFFCODE** but in DHT marker section, there is HUFFVAL list (Li, Vi,j). ***B.2.4.2 Huffman table-specification syntax*** says:

> Vi,j: Value associated with each Huffman code – Specifies, for each i, the value associated with each Huffman code of length i. The meaning of each value is determined by the Huffman coding model. The Vi,j’s are the elements of the list HUFFVAL

So I don't have HUFFCODE list I only have HUFFVAL list which comes from DHT marker. How can I get or build HUFFCODE list?

**Annex C** also defines how to build huffman tables, there is a section about how to build HUFFCODE list/table (**Figure C.2 – Generation of table of Huffman codes**) I guess I must use that to build HUFFCODE table. But it also uses BITS(i). What is that value? Does BITS(i) come from DHT marker?

From my understanding steps I must follow are:

1. Parse DHT marker to get HUFFVAL table/list
2. Build HUFFCODE table/list **by using ???**
3. Build decoder tables (MAXCODE, MINCODE, VALPTR) by using HUFFCODE tables
4. In scan marker, use DECODE and EXTEND to get huffman value by using MAXCODE, MINCODE, VALPTR tables

I'm not sure which data to pass as BITS(i) for getting HUFFCODE.

Thanks for clarification of the steps

PS: I don't want to build huffman tree, instead I want to build lookup table.

Comment: I'm not sure what step int he process you are referring to. The method in the JPEG standard does not build a tree of Huffman codes.

Comment: I think I made some progress. Annex C says "Given a list BITS (1 to 16) containing the number of codes of each size". So to get HUFFCODE I used Li values (number of Huffman code) in DHT marker as BITS(i). Now I have HUFFCODEs (I think) and I can implement DECODE and EXTEND